Calculating: $\lim_{n\to\infty}{\int_{3}^{4}}( \sqrt{-x^2+6x-8})^{n}dx$
Calculate: $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{3}^{4} \left(\sqrt{-x^2+6x-8}\right)^{n}{\rm d}x.$

I've tried to change the variable and I took it as $y=x-3$.
I have changed the limits of integrations, for $x=3$, $y=0$, and for $x=4, y=1$.
$\mbox{I replaced } x \mbox{ with } y+3 \mbox{ here }\int_{3}^{4}(\sqrt{-x^2+6x-8})^{n}{\rm d}x \mbox{ and after some basic algebra I obtained } 4\int_{0}^{1} \sqrt{(1-y^2)}^{n}dy.$

I can tell that the limit is $0$ because the function is decreasing on $[0,1]$ and I have an intuition that it may be solved with squeeze theorem but I can't find an upper sequence which converges to $0$ as $n$ goes to $\infty$.

Is the integrand $\left(\sqrt{-x^2+6x-8}\right)^n$ or $\sqrt{-x^2+6x-8^n}$? I assume the former, but just checking to be sure.

The former, I’m not yet accustomed with writing here. Thank you.

Write instead $(…)^{n/2}$.

FWIW, if $I_n$ is the integral, then $I_0 = 1$, $I_1 = \frac{\pi}{4}$, $I_2 = \frac{2}{3}$, $I_3 = \frac{3\pi}{16}$, $I_4 = \frac{8}{15}$, $I_5 = \frac{5\pi}{32}$, $I_6 = \frac{16}{35}$, $I_7 = \frac{35\pi}{256}$, $I_8 = \frac{128}{315}$, $I_9 = \frac{63\pi}{512}$, $I_{10} = \frac{256}{693}$, $I_{11} = \frac{231\pi}{2048}$, and $I_{12} = \frac{1024}{3003}$.  All results calculated by WolframAlpha.

These all satisfy the recurrence relation $I_n = \frac{n}{n + 1}I_{n-2}$.  If you can prove that rigorously (perhaps using Integration By Parts), then you can should be able to derive an explicit formula for $I_n$.

This question is similar to: How to prove $\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\cos^nxdx=0$. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. Other duplicates in this list: https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=AND%20site%3Amath.stackexchange.com%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24%5Clim_%7Bn%5Cto%5Cinfty%7D%5Cint_0%5E%7B%5Cpi%2F2%7D%5Ccos%5Ent%5C%3Bdt%24&p=1

From your work, we have that the integral is the same as
$$I_n=\int_{0}^{1} \sqrt{(1-y^2)^n}dy$$
We obviously have $I_n\geq 0$ for all $n\geq 1$.
Now, take $0<\epsilon<1$. Then, $$I_n=\int_{0}^{\epsilon} \sqrt{(1-y^2)^n}dy+\int_{\epsilon}^{1} \sqrt{(1-y^2)^n}dy$$
As the first integrand is bounded by $1$ and the second integrand is bounded above by $(1-\epsilon^2)^{n/2}$, we get $$I_n\leq \epsilon+(1-\epsilon^2)^{n/2}$$
As $1-\epsilon^2<1$, $(1-\epsilon^2)^{n/2}\to 0$ when $n\to\infty$, so that $(1-\epsilon^2)^{n/2}\leq\epsilon$ for sufficiently large $n$.
Thus, $0\leq I_n\leq 2\epsilon$ for large $n$, which proves that $I_n\to 0$.

Consider
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{n}I_n\equiv\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{n}\int_3^4\left(\sqrt{-x^2+6x-8}\right)^ndx$$
Use the substitution $u = \sqrt{n}(x-3)$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^\sqrt{n}\left(1-\frac{u^2}{n}\right)^{\frac{n}{2}}du \longrightarrow \int_0^\infty e^{-\frac{u^2}{2}}du = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}$$
by dominated convergence.
This means $I_n \sim \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2n}}$ and therefore
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}I_n = 0$$

Let $\phi(x)=-x^2+6x-8$. Then $\phi'(x)=-2x+6=0$ iff $x=3$. Clearly $x=3$ is a maximum point. It follows that on $[3,4]$, $0\leq \phi(x)\leq 1$. Then $f_n(x)=\big(\phi(x)\big)^{n/2}\leq 1$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $3\leq x\leq 4$. Clearly $\lim_n f_n(x)=0$ for all $3<x\leq 4$; hence, by dominated convergence
$$\lim_n\int^4_3\big(\phi(x)\big)^{n/2}\,dx\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}\int^4_3 0\,dx=0$$

Letting $x-3=\sin \theta$ transforms the integral into a Beta function.
$$
\begin{aligned}
I_n & =\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \cos ^n \theta \cos \theta d \theta \\
& =\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin ^{2\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-1} \theta \cos ^{2\left(\frac{n}{2}+1\right)-1} \theta d \theta \\
& =\frac{1}{2} B\left(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{n}{2}+1\right)
\end{aligned}
$$
Using the identity :
$$
B(x, y)=\frac{x+y}{x y} \cdot \frac{1}{\binom{x+y}{x}}
$$
we have
$$I_n=\frac{n+3}{4(n+2)} \frac{1}{\binom{\frac{n+3}{2}}{\frac{1}{2}}}
$$
As $\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty}\binom{\frac{n+3}{2}}{\frac{1}{2}}=\infty$, therefore we can conclude that
$$
\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} I_n=\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{n+3}{4(n+2)} \frac{1}{\left(\frac{n+3}{\frac{1}{2}}\right)}=0
$$

The only non-trivial thing about this is your substitution $x-3=\sin\theta$. How can one come up with this?

By completing squares.
